# SKProductsRequestDelegate Is not triggered when product is requested

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, sandbox, tvos, storekit

I’m reusing a class I always use that is called “StoreService” made by me and it always worked fine, but in this new project I’m working on the SKProductsRequestDelegate never gets called.

I already checked:

- Strong reference to the product request
- If the delegate is set
- If it would work with a different sandbox account
- Tested in a real device
- Tested in simulator

Nothing made it work. I also tried to implement RevenueCat SDK just for the sake of having it working somehow but even using revenuecat I get “timeout” when requesting for a product.

I’m also using StoreKit local configuration file to make purchases in simulator

Comment: Didi you find solution to the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was "fixed" by updating my Mac to macOS Ventura beta 7, Xcode 14 and tvOS 16.... it's not really a fix but at least I can now move on.

Meanwhile Im in touch with Apple Developers to understand what's the problem here, because the same block of code wasn't working in previous Xcode/macOS/tvOS

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skproductsrequestdelegate), you might face the issue with getting response on specific threads:

> Responses received by the SKProductsRequestDelegate may not be returned on a specific thread. If you make assumptions about which queue will handle delegate responses, you may encounter unintended performance and compatibility issues in the future.